# set alarm in Xamarin forms and set the next time for it from sql lite table using Broadcast receiver without using AlarmManager.SetRepeating

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, alarmmanager

I want to set the alarm on different times but want to set the next by getting the time from sqllite table by using Broadcast receiver.
I've also created dependency service

Here's what I have tried

```
public void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime)
    {

         var intent = CreateIntent(id);
        Random generator = new Random();
        _randomNumber = generator.Next(100000, 999999).ToString("D6");

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, Convert.ToInt32(_randomNumber), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
        var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();


        var todaysdate = notifyTime;

        var _UpcomingSalah = new NextSalahTimeRemaining().getNextSalahTime(todaysdate);

        var ms = (long)(_UpcomingSalah.SalahTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, Android.OS.SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() +ms, pendingIntent);

    }
```

> BroadcastReciever's  'On recieve func'

```
public override async void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
                 
     

        var sound = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource + "://" + context.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.azan);


        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(context, sound);
        r.Play();

        await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync("It's Time for salah");


        

        Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().LocalNotification("Local Notification", "sdfasdf", 0, System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));

    }
```

I'm calling the dependecy service for next time form sqllite table, the alarm works once but stops instantly after that.

Comment: I don't see any sql code.  And if this is all taking place in the Android project why do you need DependencyService?  Have you verified that the `Get<ILocalNotificationService>` is actually returning an instance and that `LocalNotification` is being called?

Comment: Thanks json for reply,

`var _UpcomingSalah = new NextSalahTimeRemaining().getNextSalahTime(todaysdate);

        var ms = (long)(_UpcomingSalah.SalahTime).TotalMilliseconds;`
The above code is responsible for returning me the next time from class "NextSalahTimeRemaining" in which I've put all the sqliite code and converting into milliseconds.
First time I'm Calling the dependency from MainActivity, that works fine and gives the alarm. But when I call it from OnReccive function it doesn't work.

Comment: You could recheck the BroadcastReceiver. The OnReceive is override in Andoird. Why you use the DependencyService in it?